# Protecting columns in excel using C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel, excel-automation

I am attempting to write into an excel sheet some data and after writing in the necessary data, I would like to protect the cells against editing by making them non editable. After this operation, some data will be updated on the unprotected cells by the sheet users which I will then use and read from to carry out some processing activity.

1. Can someone help me out with specifically, how do I lock a column from editing in excel?
2. How do you write using C# into a protected column?
3. How do you read using C# from a protected column?

Simple references to examples would help me out greatly.
PS: If you are more comfortable with VB.NET even the references of how to do this on that would be helpful.

Comment: From what I see you can't do that in plain Excel... so there won't be a way to do it via C# or VB.NET... IMHO the concept of "expecting that data put into an Excel Worksheet will come back unmodified whil other parts are editable by the user" seems risky at best...

Comment: Risky how? I am allowing users to edit some values in the sheet while I protect other values from them editing. I have seen excels where cells which act as the header and tags are non editable while other cells the user can enter values. So I am supposing something on similar lines should work here as well.

Comment: It is indeed possible to modify an Excel file despite such "protection". ANY data you give out to a user and then comes back (with some data added) should be verified before you process it further (users are of very different types with different skillsets).

Answer (score 1):

For Excel cell to be in non-editable mode two things have to be taken care of:

1) The Excel cell should be Locked

> ws.get_Range("Location", Type.Missing).Locked = true;

2) The Excel worksheet should also be locked

> ```
> ws.Protect("SecurityCode", true, true, true,
>             Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, true, Type.Missing,
>             Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
>             Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
> //where ws is the worksheet object
> ```

For your Second question to read through an Protected cell, this can be done directly

```
string CellValue = ws.get_Range("Location", Type.Missing).Value2.ToString();
//Now depending upon the CellValue you can write your own Logic.
```

Comment: Yup..If you wish to make the entire column non-editable, just include ws.get_Range("Location", Type.Missing).EntireColumn.Locked = true;